# Simple Android layout issue

Tags: android, layout

I want to do something very simple.  I want a layout that has a spinner at the top, followed by a List View, followed by a Linear Layout at the very bottom that wraps some buttons.  I want the List View to expand to fill the space between the spinner and the buttons, no matter how big the window is. I have been trying this with a Linear Layout wrapping all three elements and I have tried every combination of Wrap Content and Fill Parent for Layout_Height that I can think of but unless I hard code the List View Layout_Height to say 300 dip, the buttons are pushed off the screen. I know that there must be an easy way to do this but I am at my wits end.  I have tried everything I can think of.

Here is the code that works with the hard-coded height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/fileType"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dip" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ManageFiles_DeleteItem"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Delete item" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ManageFiles_DeleteAll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Delete all" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ManageFiles_DisplayItem"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Display item" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ManageFiles_OKcustom"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_margin="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="OK" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ManageFiles_CancelCustom"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_margin="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

`

Comment: What is your total height of device and what height do you need for each spinner ,listview,linearlayout

Comment: @Arju, What kind of framework are you thinking of? Are you really thinking of an Android device?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something as simple as

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/spinner1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Button1" />

<Button
    android:id="@id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Button2" />
```

The trick is to use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about Relative Layout.  I used layout_weight per another suggestion and it solved the problem but I think I will try Relative Layout now just to see if it works and then I will have it in my repertoire.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Following

```
android:weightSum="Your total length" //in your main layout

android:layout_weight="" //in each of your listview,spinner,linearlayout
```

Eg: if u need equal space for all 3 elements use

```
android:weightSum="3"
```

then in

```
Spinner
android:layout_weight="1"
/>

ListView
android:layout_weight="1"
/>

LinearLayout
android:layout_weight="1"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use weight, give weight of two to the list view and 1 each to the spinner and layout at bottom containing the buttons you can then vary the weight and check out which suits you more.

Comment: This didn't seem to work at all.  When the list was populated, it floated to the top and was not very tall. And the button layout at the bottom went half-way off the screen.  Why is this so hard???

Comment: You forgot to tell me one vital piece of information!!  For this to work, you have to set the layout_height of all three elements to 0px.  Now it works!

Comment: ya you have to do that, actually i had tried to edit the layout you had posted and post it back but there was some formating issue with the stackoverflow editor so i could not post back

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this way it will fit to all screen size.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ftr_btn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ManageFiles_DeleteItem"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Delete item" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ManageFiles_DeleteAll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Delete all" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ManageFiles_DisplayItem"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Display item" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ManageFiles_OKcustom"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_margin="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="OK" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ManageFiles_CancelCustom"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_margin="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/fileType"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ftr_btn"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fileType" >
</ListView>
```